# Generic ToolTip for ((TextBox)sender) when TextBox has focus

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to implement a ToolTip for multiple textboxes. I currently have the folllowing

```
//selects all text in current textbox on textbox selection and changes BackColor to show which textbox has focus
    private void txt_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }
```

I tried adding

```
ToolTip.Show("message", ((TextBox)sender));
```

but this isn't working, i'm sure the answer is very simple but im new to this please bear with me, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToolTip is the name of the class, probably not the name of the instance:

My guess would be, try this:

```
toolTip1.Show("message", ((TextBox)sender));
```

Of course, you need to document what "not working" means.  Look in your code or the designer for the name you are using for your ToolTip control.

Comment: ah I see, I hadn't declared the ToolTip anywhere in my code:  `//selects all text in current textbox on textbox selection and changes BackColor to show which textbox has focus  
        private void txt_enter(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();  
            ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.LightBlue;  
            ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();   
            toolTip1.Show("message", ((TextBox)sender), 100,0,3000);  
        }  ` this now works, thanks with your help I spotted my mistake